# Android 2.3.6 - USB Tethering and ADB at the same time

Tags: android, usb, adb, tethering

I'm trying to use USB tethering and ADB at the same time with a rooted Android 2.3.6 (yeah, old, I know) but I can't, when I activate USB tethering, adb stops recognizing the device.
Is it how Android 2.3.6 works? Is there anything I can do to have both working?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's rooted, just do ADB over wifi.

Comment: I need to get the tethered internet connection on the same computer that I'll run adb, then I cannot connect the computer to another wifi network, can I?

Comment: Actually you should be able to connect a computer to two networks, though autoconfiguration wizards may get in your way.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Will I be able to use internet connection from tether and wifi to adb at the same time?

Comment: Presumably but it depends on the details of your non-standard (rooted) device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use the tethering option, disable it.

install [proxoid app](https://code.google.com/archive/p/proxoid/) and start the server on your device. Then configure your system proxy for HTTP to be localhost on port 8080 and run:

adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080

the first is the proxoid port and the second the one of your proxy

**Source:**
http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Tether-an-Android-Phone-Using-Proxoid

Comment: or you can enable adb over network and do both at once :) not sure if stock roms support this, cyanogenmod does though.